# PHP dump variable as PHP code

Tags: php

I'm looking for a function to dump a multi-dimension array so that the output is valid php code.

Suppose I have the following array:

```
$person = array();
$person['first'] = 'Joe';
$person['last'] = 'Smith';
$person['siblings'] = array('Jane' => 'sister', 'Dan' => 'brother', 'Paul' => 'brother');
```

Now I want to dump the $person variable so the the dump string output, if parsed, will be valid php code that redefines the $person variable.

So doing something like:

```
dump_as_php($person);
```

Will output:

```
$person = array(
    'first'    => 'Joe',
    'last'     => 'Smith',
    'siblings' => array(
        'Jane' => 'sister',
        'Dan'  => 'brother',
        'Paul' => 'brother'
    )
);
```

Comment: Why do you need this? If you're intending on `eval` ing it later, I would say "forget that, use JSON instead".

Comment: I'm fetching some data from db and dumping it into dynamically created php files for faster future access to that data.

Comment: Isn't this what Caching is for? Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

> var_export() gets structured
>   information about the given variable.
>   It is similar to var_dump() with one
>   exception: the returned representation
>   is valid PHP code.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I need. So simple. They thought of everything with the built-in functions  :)

Comment: I've never even heard of this before! Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

[`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

This is useful for storing or passing PHP values around without losing their type and structure. In contrast to `var_export` this will handle circular references as well in case you want to dump large objects graphs.

The output will not be PHP code though.